# Kubernetes in docker for Ubuntu

Tags: kubernetes

Is there an ubuntu version of Kubernetes in docker for Ubuntu, that works like docker for mac(https://blog.docker.com/2018/01/docker-mac-kubernetes/). 
and docker for windows (https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#kubernetes)

minikube consumes lots of resource, and I want to try out a lighter alternative, which I found docker for mac that supports kubernetes, but my machine is ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Did you look to https://github.com/rancher/k3d ?

Answer (score 1):

As you may know there are a lot of projects that offer K8S solution, Minikube is the closest to an official mini distribution for local testing and development, but if you wanna try lightweight options you can check:

- **[Kind](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind)** runs Kubernetes clusters in Docker containers. It supports multi-node clusters as well as HA clusters. Because it runs K8s in Docker, kind can run on Windows, Mac, and Linux. Kind may not have developer-friendly features.
- **[K3s](https://github.com/rancher/k3s)** is ma project by Rancher as a lightweight Kubernetes offering suitable for edge environments, IoT devices, CI pipelines, and even ARM devices, like Raspberry Pi's. It runs on any Linux distribution without any additional external dependencies or tools. K3s provides lightweight by replacing docker with containerd, and using sqlite3 as the default DB (instead of etcd). This solution consumes 512 MB of RAM and 200 MB of disk space.
- **[K3d](https://github.com/rancher/k3d)**
  It is based on a k3s which is a lightweight kubernetes distribution (similar to kind).
- **[Microk8s](https://microk8s.io/)** runs upstream Kubernetes as native services on Linux systems supporting snap. A good option if you are running Ubuntu on your Laptop. There is a very good [installation tutorial](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/install-a-local-kubernetes-with-microk8s#0):

And there are plenty more. You can check what solution suits you best.

Answer (score 0):

Check [kind](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind) it is kubernetes in docker.